# Kafka with Docker Problems

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to deploy kafka by docker-compose file or evenby installing kafka image and run it manually. Both of these steps are giving to me that error when I start to run kafka server(broker)

INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=188.226.151.167:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@323b36e0 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-05-16 13:44:49,903] INFO Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2017-05-16 13:44:49,909] INFO Opening socket connection to server 188.226.151.167/188.226.151.167:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2017-05-16 13:44:55,904] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)

Could anyone has clear explanation of what happens and the clear explanation about how to fix it

Comment: Can you please share your docker-compose?Also, please share the docker version and OS you are working on.

Comment: docker compose file   version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.99.100
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock

Comment: OS version : Ubuntu 16.04 Docker Version: Docker version 17.04.0-ce

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
kafka:
  network_mode: 'bridge'
  image: wurstmeister/kafka
  links:
    - zookeeper
  environment:
    HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "hostname -I | awk -F' ' '{print $$1}'"
    KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
    KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
zookeeper:
  network_mode: 'bridge'
  image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
```

Answer (score 0):

I have setup my docker compose as this and everything works perfectly:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
    hostname: zookeeper
    container_name: zookeeper
    volumes:
      - /tmp/docker/zk1/logs:/logs
      - /tmp/docker/zk1/data:/data
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test1:1:1,test2:1:1"
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $$2}'"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /tmp/docker/kafka/logs:/logs
      - /tmp/docker/kafka/data:/data
      - ./tmp/docker/kafka/kafka-logs:/kafka
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
```

I have setup the ports to be like '2181:2181' and not just '2181' so that to be accessible outside my container.

I have also set the volumes so that every time I restart the container to remember all the data from previous time.

Comment: When I made this docker compose file up these errors appears to me <code> Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /brokers/topics/test1/partitions/0  and this error <code> caught end of stream exception
zookeeper1   | EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15c1a74ce3c0002, likely client has closed socket

Comment: Are you sure this docker compose file doesn't depend on any another file ?

Comment: I want know what is the [link] HOSTNAME_COMMAND ? 
Because when I tried to type this command 
[command] route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $$2}' 
in terminal nothing appears to me
Is this the local host IP or docker machine IP ?

Comment: I don't know why you get this errors. I just created a test directory with a docker-compose.yml with the code that I have posted above and it perfectly works. You do not necessarily need to set the KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS though, you can do that through your application initialization. To be honest I was testing that command but I use other topics that I dynamically create through my app. 
As for the command I found it on the [wurstmeister/kafka](https://hub.docker.com/r/wurstmeister/kafka/) and without this HOSTNAME_COMMAND it was not working so I set it up as suggested.

Comment: SOLVED By disabling docker machine firewall command : ufw disable

Answer (score 0):

It solved all kafka with docker connection by outside machines by disabling firewall connection
Command:
ufw disable